# ¿que error se esta cometiendo al agregar las imágenes?

Tags: html

a primera vista, se supone que las imágenes están agregadas correctamente en el código de la página y deberían funcionar, pero sólo dejan un gran espacio en la pantalla

```html
<img src="Schottisches_HochlandrindPW.jpg" / height="500px">
            <p> <font color="808080"> "Schottisches Hochlandrind, Deutschland" by <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Schottisches_Hochlandrind.jpg">Darkone</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5">CC BY-SA 2.5</a>, via Wikimedia Commons </font> </p>
        <h2>Temperament</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando colocas

```
src="Schottisches_HochlandrindPW.jpg"
```

La página en el proceso de carga busca ese archivo en la misma carpeta de la página, sino lo encuentra genera un "espacio" de

```
height="500px"
```

Debes entregar una ruta en el src que contenga lo que quieres mostrar, por ejemplo esta

```
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Schottisches_Hochlandrind.jpg"
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Schottisches_Hochlandrind.jpg" / height="500px">
            <p> <font color="808080"> "Schottisches Hochlandrind, Deutschland" by <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Schottisches_Hochlandrind.jpg">Darkone</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5">CC BY-SA 2.5</a>, via Wikimedia Commons </font> </p>
        <h2>Temperament</h2>
```

Comment: Esa barra **/** antes del **height** está mal. debe ir justo antes del **>**. Así: `<img src="img.jpg" height="500px"/>` aunque no es necesaria.

Comment: Eso del slash/barra es bastante interesante, según la especifición html el slash es opcional, o sea no es obligatorio colocarlo en la etiqueta IMG. Preferí dejarlo tal como estaba en la pregunta original ya que no tenía un efecto negativo ni positivo.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element

Comment: Error, que no haga nada no significa que no esté mal. Y en efecto, yo mismo lo dije, no es obligatorio, pero si lo haces DEBES ponerla donde es, no en cualquier sitio. Al final debemos dar al OP todas las correcciones posibles, no estoy en contra de tu respuesta, solo quise aclararle al OP que esa barra en ese sitio está mal.